Screen Freeze after sleep mode
When I lock my laptop using the shortcut (WINDOW + L), occasionally upon reopening, the screen freezes. It's not a consistent issue, but it occurs about one-third of the time. To resolve it, I've found that I need to either log out or restart the laptop. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this recurring problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
You can see in image it makes menus invisible expect for application menu.

